# How can I use a DLL from one project in a second project in Visual Studio 2010 using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7  64-bit system. I am coding in vb.net.  I am trying to use the SpreadsheetGear DLL (D:\VS2010Code\Report Depository\Bin\SpreadsheetGear.dll) in my DashInApps (D:\TWhitsett\DashInApps) project to load my output data to Excel.  Can someone assist and guide me in the right direction to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and click 'Add Reference'. Then point to the SpreadsheetGear DLL in question. You can't just put it in the bin directory and expect it to work without loading it into the project first.